# No way to go to end of document in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and Dell Latitude E7450 and just pressing <kbd>End</kbd> doesn't do it. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> doesn't do it. In fact there is no way to go to the bottom of a Google Drive document. They just won't let me.

it's written online that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> would do it with PC but that's a lie.

Comment: What web browser are you using? As of October 2019 do still have this problem?

Answer (score 4):

On my mac and with the latest version of Chrome I can simple press ⌘ + down arrow to move to the very end of the document. Hope it's that simple for everyone else.

Comment: This is the solution, thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this post when I was looking for "how to go to the bottom of google docs". Didn't find any solutions and went ahead and tried by using a random combination of keyboard shortcuts on my Dell laptop.

**Control + Fn + Home** ==> Took me to beginning of the page.
**Control + Fn + End**  ==> Took me to the bottom of the page.

It may not be the solution the beginner of this thread was looking for.
But, I hope this will help many others like me.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

I am using a Mac with a magic wireless keyboard (without an end key). There doesn't seem to be a keyboard shortcut for this.

I have documents that I often need to jump straight to the end of after loading them. My workaround is as follows:

1. Add a piece of text at the very end of the document, such as "END OF DOCUMENT".
2. Select the text, go to the insert menu, and select "bookmark".
3. Copy the link for the bookmark.
4. Add some text at the top of the document, such as "GO TO END".
5. Hyperlink that text to the bookmark.

I can then jump to the end of the document by clicking on the link at the top of the document. I'm sorry that I cannot give you an exact answer to your question, but I hope this workaround helps.

Answer (score 0):

To go to end of a Google Document, just press <kbd>End</kbd>

Note: Tested on Windows 10, Chrome version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) with 104 keyboard with latin american layout.

Answer (score 0):

On a macbookpro fn+downarrow will page down, and fn+rightarrow will move to the end of the browser page.

- fn+rightarrow works as intended on browser pages
- fn+rightarrow does not do anything in Google Docs

Answer (score 0):

I am on a Chrome OS machine. END does not work to jump to end of doc. Ctrl + END *does* jump to the end of the entire doc, even if multiple pages long.

Answer (score -2):

It works as long as you have the number lock on your 10-key turned off.